# Can't edit my profile

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, profile-page

I've been low-key following all the stuff with the new CoC and figured, fine I'll give my pronouns or whatever. Go to make the change and keep getting stopped because apparently my profile picture is an 'invalid image type'.

Did jpegs suddenly become forbidden? This has been my pic since forever and I'd prefer to not change.

EDIT1: I just made a revision to the About Me section for my profile on Parenting.SE and had it save correctly.

I then returned to RPG.SE and attempted to update the About Me section and had this same error occur.

The issue appears to be related, in some manner, to RPG.SE. I do not know if this issue is indicative of some sort of glitch with the coding for RPG.SE.

Comment: That's weird. I tried setting [your picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzmpQ.jpg) in my profile and it worked just fine (although I didn't actually save the change). Might be a bug somewhere. I wonder if just downloading the picture and reuploading it would help?

Comment: Hello! Tried to repro this and can't reproduce (see the new snazzy JPEG in my avatar). Are you still having the issue?

Comment: @SaraChipps issue is still occurring when I tried to add my pronouns in the About Me section and save. Issue occurred with both 'Save changes just for this community' and 'Save and copy changes to all public communities'.

Comment: Strange, I just updated mine and it worked. Mind sending over a screenshoot? You can attach to your question.

Comment: @SaraChipps I think I fixed it per my work around edit above. I'd held off on messing around with the picture itself because I was worried about losing it and not being able to find another copy. I'm going to make it into an answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Steps followed on a work around attempt:

1. Choose to edit profile.
2. Click 'Change Picture'
3. Click on 'Uploaded Picture', not 'Upload a new picture'. The current picture will automatically resize when you do this. In my case, it appears to stretch vertically.
4. Click 'Save changes just for this community'.
5. This saved successfully and now my About Me section is updated.

I'm just speculating, but it seems that at some point after I uploaded the original picture, the jpeg's dimensions got squished in some manner that maybe made it not comply with the profile picture requirements.

I'm not sure if the squishing might've happened after a hat event or something but I don't think it's possible for a normal user to bypass the profile picture requirements. So I'm not sure what happened there.

I'm unsure why the issue didn't occur on other sites on the network, but maybe gremlins.